# Do Parse Cloud Code triggers need response

Tags: ios, parse-platform, triggers, parse-cloud-code

Since I'm kinda new to cloud code, I have the question mentioned above!

1) Do cloud code triggers, beforeSave - afterSave etc, need to call response.success and response.error when they are done?

2) If so, is it possible for the client to receive that response?

**Edit: For the first question, I realised that it's necessary for the "before" triggers only...**
The second question remains unanswered!

Answer (score 1):

In a `beforeSave()` trigger, the `response.sucess()` is returned to the client like this.
It's only in case of error that it could be interesting to return a specific message (for a business validation before save for i.e)
So in your cloud code you could write :

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("MyObject", function(request, response) {

  //business validation then if fail :
  response.error("there was an error blabla...");
}
});
```

Then the Client will receive a Parse Exception with the corresponding message

Comment: So, is it possible to use afterSave triggers, for a chat app? If user A posts a new message, is it possible for user B to instantly receive that message?

Comment: maybe by using Parse Live Query but I don't think it is implemented yet in android; (don't know for IOS)